# ActionCable does not run connect method upon connecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm trying to work with `ActionCable`, but right now I'm trying to do the seemingly trivial task of trying to get a user id in a channel when I have the connection identified by `current_user` and its set properly in the `connect` method. I feel like I'm missing something completely obvious here. Here are my two relevant files

### application_cable/connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = env['warden'].user
    end

  end
end
```

### notifications_channel.rb

```
class NotificationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from("push_notification_channel_#{connection.current_user.id}")
  end
end
```

For some reason `connection.current_user` is `nil` in notifications channel. Am I just missing something really obvious?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, Eli? I appear to be having the same issue.

Comment: @matt_goodall No unfortunately not. I ended up going another direction I believe.

Comment: Yeah, I've just rebuilt my app hoping to find the point at which it broke. Were/are you using CanCan for authorisation by any chance? I suspect it might have been causing my problem with the `connect`